# Cannot get a TJclUpdateArchive to add a compressed file to an already existing archive

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, jedi

I have been working with the JclCompression library attempting to add a file to an existing archive. Unfortunately, when `archive.compress` is called in my function below, it deletes the original archive and replaces it with an archive (with the same file name) containing just the single compressed file that I am attempting to add. All of the original files have been removed.

```
function TMyCompression.AddZipItems(const archiveFileName: string; const itemsToZip: TList<TMyCompressionItem>): boolean;
var
  archive: TJclUpdateArchive;
  archiveClass: TJclUpdateArchiveClass;
  packedItemName : string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  archiveClass := GetArchiveFormats.FindUpdateFormat(archiveFileName);
  archive := archiveClass.Create(archiveFileName);
  if NOT Assigned(archive) then
    Result := FALSE
  else
    try
      for i := 0 to itemsToZip.Count -1 do
        begin
          packedItemName := RootPath(itemsToZip[i].Name);
          if itemsToZip[i].IsDirectory then
            archive.AddDirectory(packedItemName, itemsToZip[i].Name, true, true)
          else
            archive.AddFile(packedItemName, itemsToZip[i].Name);
        end;
      archive.Compress;
    finally
      archive.Free;
    end;
 end;
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with the JclCompression tool?

**Edits:**

Removed a couple of internal function calls that did not affect the code.

Other Delphi Compression Tools I have tried and rejected:

- Delphi XE's internal System.Zip; there are no hooks for any type of progress or feedback.
- TurboPower Abbrevia v5; I have used this tool successfully for decades with the old zip32 compression. However, I now need zip64 support and the latest version failed on the first two over 4GB files I tried (As I recall it was an invalid block size). Both files could be opened with 7-zip and with Windows File Explorer.
- Shell to the internal zip tool that Windows File Explorer uses; I let a 6GB compressed file run overnight and when I returned in the morning it still reported 20 hours to go.

7-Zip is extremely fast, allows for good feedback, and has been thoroughly exercised and tested.

Comment: what formats other than .ZIP you going to process? if none, then Delphi from XE2 has built-in basic ZIP support

Comment: what is `archive.ReplaceVolumes` ? what is `InitCompressArchive` ????

Comment: If you are going to use a third party library, tpAbbrevia is the best

Comment: I have addressed the current set of comments in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

> All of the original files have been removed

Use **ListFiles** method

```
procedure ArchivingLog;
var
  file_name,
  archive_name   : string;
  archive        : TJclCompressArchive;
  archive_format : TJclCompressArchiveClass;
begin
  file_name := format('%s\111.log', [GetCurrentDir]);

  if (FileExists(file_name)) then
  begin
    archive_name   := GetCurrentDir + '\111.log.7z';
    archive_format := GetArchiveFormats.FindUpdateFormat(archive_name);

    if archive_format <> nil then
    begin
      archive := archive_format.Create(archive_name);

      if (FileExists(archive_name)) then
        (archive as TJcl7zUpdateArchive).ListFiles; //without this call deletes all previous files in the archive


      (archive as TJcl7zUpdateArchive).AddFile(ExtractFileName(file_name), file_name);

      try
        (archive as TJcl7zUpdateArchive).Compress;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(archive);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```